# Баг с установкой LPMINMAXINFO

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дело такое, при обработке сообщения `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` и установке значений `LPMINMAXINFO`, при первой установке, т.е. при запуске окна, все нормально, но стоит попробовать изменить размер, и переопределить данные передаваемые по ссылке, как окно начинает вести себя не адекватно. Ниже приведу пример, если потребуется весь класс окна приложу и его.

**Если быть точнее то при установке максимально допустимого размера ширины/высоты.**
*По данной [ссылке](http://himiko.pw/window_bug.mp4) можно наглядно посмотреть что происходит с окном*
[image]

Обработка сообщения `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`:

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
{
    LPMINMAXINFO lp_mmi = reinterpret_cast<LPMINMAXINFO>(lparam);
    on_min_max_info(m_min_max_info_);
    if (m_min_max_info_.min_width != 0)
    {
        lp_mmi->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_min_max_info_.min_width;
    }
    if (m_min_max_info_.min_height != 0)
    {
        lp_mmi->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_min_max_info_.min_height;
    }
    if (m_min_max_info_.max_width != 0)
    {
        lp_mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.x = m_min_max_info_.max_width;
    }
    if (m_min_max_info_.max_height != 0)
    {
        lp_mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.y = m_min_max_info_.max_height;
    }
}
break;
```

Сам метод `on_min_max_info` это чисто виртуальная ф-ция.

```
virtual void on_min_max_info(window_min_max_data_t& min_max_data) = 0;
```

Структура:

```
struct window_min_max_data
{
    int min_width = 0;
    int min_height = 0;
    int max_width = 0;
    int max_height = 0;
    void* window_ptr = nullptr;
} typedef window_min_max_data_t;
```

Далее даю определение виртуальной ф-ции в дочернем классе.

```
void window::on_min_max_info(window_min_max_data_t& min_max_data)
{
    set_min_max_info(min_max_data, 0, 0, 640, 480, true);
}
```

Метод `set_min_max_info`:

```
void window::set_min_max_info(window_min_max_data_t& data, int max_w, int max_h, int min_w, int min_h,
                              const bool adjust_window_rect) const
{
    if (adjust_window_rect)
    {
        RECT r1 = { 0,0,min_w,min_h };
        RECT r2 = { 0,0,max_w, max_h };
        AdjustWindowRect(&r1, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);
        AdjustWindowRect(&r2, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);
        min_w = r1.right - r1.left;
        min_h = r1.bottom - r1.top;
        max_w = r2.right - r2.left;
        max_h = r2.bottom - r2.top;
    }
    memcpy_s(&data.min_width, sizeof data.min_width, &min_w, sizeof min_w);
    memcpy_s(&data.min_height, sizeof data.min_height, &min_h, sizeof min_h);
    memcpy_s(&data.max_width, sizeof data.max_width, &max_w, sizeof max_w);
    memcpy_s(&data.max_height, sizeof data.max_height, &max_h, sizeof max_h);
}
```

При этом, если задать реальное значение максимальной ширины/высоты, то все работает корректно. В чем может быть загвоздка то?

Comment: По вашей гифке не понятно, то ли это окно лагает, то ли гифка. А другие сообщения обрабатываются? Код на вид вроде правильно должен работать. Непонятно только зачем столько `memcpy_s`.

Comment: @VTT, другие сообщения обрабатываются корректно, окно при установке максимальной ширины как `0`, т.е. игнорировать, просто напросто не растягивается, и не меняет размер, Если тянуть за верхнюю границу, то оно начинает летать по сему раб. пространству.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, спустя некоторое время, нашел проблему, а заключается она в следующем:

**Когда создаем `RECT` со значениями `{0,0,0,0}`, то `AdjustWindowRect` проводит манипуляции с данным `RECT` и задает отрицательные значения, т.к. рамки окна все таки есть. Можно сделать так, передать стиль окна как `0` или же не применять трансформацию `RECT` если одно из значений нулевое.**

```
void window::set_min_max_info(window_min_max_data_t& data, int max_w, int max_h, int min_w, int min_h,
                              const bool adjust_window_rect) const
{
    if (adjust_window_rect)
    {
        RECT r1 = { 0,0,min_w,min_h };
        RECT r2 = { 0,0,max_w, max_h };
        AdjustWindowRect(&r1, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);
        if(wax_w > 0 || max_h > 0)
        {
            AdjustWindowRect(&r2, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);
        }
        min_w = r1.right - r1.left;
        min_h = r1.bottom - r1.top;
        max_w = r2.right - r2.left;
        max_h = r2.bottom - r2.top;
    }
    data.min_width = min_w;
    data.min_height = min_h;
    data.max_width = max_w;
    data.max_height = max_h;
}
```